# Nodejs filestream concurrency

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-io, concurrency

it looks to me like I have a concurrency problem in nodejs. I am aware of the fact that this is not supposed to be possible.

I am processing data by the line from a file and writing it to another file also in lines. In the output file I notice that lines are being overwritten meaning that every now and then I see lines in the output that seem to be overwritten half way by other lines. 
I read the data from a read stream. it looks roughly like this:

```
let iStream = fs.createReadStream(inputFile);
let oStream = fs.createWriteStream(outputFile);
let remaining = '';

iStream.on('data',(data)=>{
  remaining += data;
  let line = remaining.split(/\r?\n/);
  let lines = line.length;
  if(lines > 0) {
    remaining = line[lines - 1];
    line.length = lines - 1;
    line.forEach((curr)=>{
      oStream.write(processLine(curr));
    });
});
```

Is there any possibility of this scheme producing write failures or do I have to look somewhere else ?

Comment: What does `processLine()` do? Is it entirely synchronous?  FYI, you can simplify your code with `remaining = line.pop()`.

Comment: Also, note that `.write()` returns  boolean that indicates whether the output buffer is full and you have to wait for the `drain` event to start writing again.  See [the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback).

Comment: You might want to use a [transform stream](http://codewinds.com/blog/2013-08-20-nodejs-transform-streams.html) and then use `.pipe()` which will handle all the flow control for you.

Comment: I would guess that you're overflowing the write buffer and thus losing data.

Comment: Thanks that sounds like it is what I am doing. It ids a lot of data and I have actually wondered where the flow control comes in..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a buffer overflow issue.  You are likely overflowing the write buffer, but not paying any attention to flow control.

You can either pass a callback into `.write()` and only proceed with the next write when that callback is called or you can pay attention to the return value from `.write()` and when it returns `false`, you have to then wait for the `drain` event on the stream before writing some more.

Another approach would be to write a [transform stream](http://codewinds.com/blog/2013-08-20-nodejs-transform-streams.html) and then use `.pipe()` and let the streaming infrastructure manage the flow control for you.

Comment: Transformer works like charm and way less sourcecode.. Thanks.