# Node js sending large amount of data ::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Trying to send large amount of data to the frontend. Here is my code to create huge data.

```
router.get('/getDataGB', function(req, res) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('download.json', 'utf8'));
        var k=0;
        var result={};
        for(var i=0; i<6800; i++){
           console.log(i);
           res.write(JSON.stringify(obj));// writing same text to increase data amount.
        }
        res.end();

    });
```

However after sending after some data (around half MB), running into an error `net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING`

Can someone throw some clue ? How to fix this ?? or is there complete new way to handle this much data ?

Comment: Hello, If you use node.js 8.0, trry with update node.js 8.1.1 : https://github.com/glenjamin/webpack-hot-middleware/issues/210

Comment: @CoursesWeb Tried that. No luck :(

Comment: When writing a lot of data with `res.write()`, you have to pay attention to flow control on the stream.  You are probably filling the buffer, continuing to write and not paying attention to when the stream is ready for writing again.  See https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback.

Comment: Similar issue: [nodejs file stream concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42266202/nodejs-filestream-concurrency/42268091#42268091).

Comment: buffer the file directly and send it as an "entity"  that is bytes... not as a file-to-json string. Have the client and server agree on gzip'd and on chuncked . verify your headers with a tool like curl at the cli...